Issues with fixing wordpress site's formatting with images
I am trying to fix the images on a WordPress site by replacing the missing ones with the original images from the site's owner. The images were corrupted/deleted before I was brought in to help, and while I can insert new images into the page I can't seem to put them in the same place as the original, which is a blank frame right now as seen in the attached picture. I also can't move anything manually above the H1 of the page.

I can't move the new image into the spot of the blank frame, or even above the header in either the standard WordPress editor or Elementor. I also can't delete or interact with the blank frame. I admit WordPress isn't exactly my wheelhouse so I'd appreciate any insight on how to fix this, thanks.

Is the corrupted image perhaps the Featured image? rather than an image in the content. The H1 is probably the page/post title, so if the image loads above that it's most likely not part of the builder/block editor content and is added via the template.
